# Keep only the first three divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, execute

I own a div and within it thousands of others, but I like to keep only the first 3, how to make it work with jquery? Exemple:

```
<div class="owner">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div> 
  <div class="child"></div> -> DELETE
  <div class="child"></div> -> DELETE
  <div class="child"></div> -> DELETE
  <div class="child"></div> -> DELETE 
  [...]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those jquery solutions do work. But if you also want to do it the CSS way, you can simply do:

```
.owner .child:nth-child(1n+4) { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:gt` selector along with `.hide()` or `.remove()`:

```
$('.owner .child:gt(2)').hide();
```

or

```
$('.owner .child:gt(2)').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `slice()`

```
$('.owner .child').slice(3).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as Milind wrote, you can remove them by `:gt` selector.

But there is another way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var index = $(".child").length;
   while (index--) {
       if(index > 2){
           ($('.child')[index]).remove();
       }
   }   
});
```

This way is more simple to understand.

I've attached [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shugxcyu/) example to the post.